# How to re install internet explorer 11?

Tags: installation, windows-8.1, internet-explorer-11

So when I first got my laptop, I completely uninstalled IE 11.  So it is not in my system at all.  Unfortunately I now have to re install it to use certain programs?  I've been searching for a link but no luck.  I have windows 8.1.

Comment: Control Panel > Programs > Turn Windows features on or off > Internet Explorer http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/how-to-turn-internet-explorer-off

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to **Control Panel** → **Programs** → **Turn Windows features on or off** and check the box for **Internet Explorer**.